# How to choose the order of variable elimination in Bayes Network

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian-network

I have the following Bayes net with me.

[image]

I want to find P(+h|+e). So I have to find A = P(+h,+e) and B = P(+e) to find P(+h|+e). I wanted to follow variable elimination for find the probability. Taking different orders is giving me different probabilities. How should I choose my order of the variable elimination for accurate calculation of P(+h|+e)?

1. Will it be okay if I calculate P(+h,+u,+e) and eliminating +u instead of finding P(+i, +h, +t, +u, +e) and eliminating +i,+t and +u for finding P(+h,+e)?
2. How do I calculate P(+e)?